# Checking form's CountOfLines

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to improve a report I made to document databases, by adding a VBA line count to Modules and Forms. The following code works perfectly in a standard module:

```
Sub test()
    Dim accObj As AccessObject, bwasOpen As Boolean, objName As String
    objName = "Form1"
    Set accObj = CurrentProject.AllForms(objName)
    bwasOpen = accObj.IsLoaded
    If Not bwasOpen Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm objName, acDesign, WindowMode:=acHidden
    End If
    If Forms(objName).HasModule Then
        DoCmd.OpenModule "Form_" & objName
        Debug.Print Modules("Form_" & objName).CountOfLines
    End If
    If Not bwasOpen Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, objName, acSaveNo
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I use a similar code in the report itself, I have an error. And since that error is happening in the class module (the report), I feel a bit stuck with debugging. The code in the report:

```
    Set accObj = CurrentProject.AllForms(objName)
    bwasOpen = accObj.IsLoaded
    If Not bwasOpen Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm objName, acDesign, WindowMode:=acHidden  'Breaks here
    End If
    If Forms(objName).HasModule Then
        DoCmd.OpenModule "Form_" & objName
        GetExtraInfo = Modules("Form_" & objName).CountOfLines
    End If
    If Not bwasOpen Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, objName, acSaveNo
    End If
```

The code is called from a report control using =GetExtraInfo(). The whole thing works well, except this new part where I want to return the CountOfLines for Forms.

Update: I have added some error trapping, and it gives error:
**2486  -   You can't carry out this action at the present time**

The whole db can be downloaded [here](https://sites.google.com/site/idevlopcode/devlopment-library/dbDocu.mdb?attredirects=0&d=1), its's only 300 KB.  The report is named "rptObjList". 
The "bad" code has been commented out. It is an Access 2003 db.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can freely open the forms and reports you need during the Report.Activate or Report.Open events... Unfortunately there's no convenient time to close them afterwards... I fiddled for awhile and couldn't help but have design view reports in the background or the part with the reports not work. I'm thinking you'll probably need to retrieve the info during the Activate or Open event and then store it in a variable that GetExtraInfo checks, if you don't want to leave extra stuff open that is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code opens a form and checks its `.HasModule` property.  And if the form has a module, you open that module to check `.CountOfLines`.  However, you need not open the module to determine its `.CountOfLines`.  And I would try to avoid opening the form, too.

```
? VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Form_Form1").CodeModule.CountOfLines
 6
```

If you ask for `.CountOfLines` for a module which doesn't exist, such as the following, you can trap error #9 ('*Subscript out of range*') to give you an alternative to checking the `.HasModule` property:

```
? VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("bogus").CodeModule.CountOfLines
```

Or you could check for the code module with a function similar to minimally tested `ModuleExists()` outlined below.

Note I'm unsure how helpful my suggestions will be because I struggled to follow your code.  Furthermore I unwisely chose to step through the code behind `rptObjList` and became frustrated by all the unhandled errors when it calls `GetDesc()` for objects which have no `Description` property.  I just gave up.

```
Public Function ModuleExists(ByVal pModule As String, _
        Optional ByVal pProject As String = "") As Boolean

    Dim blnReturn As Boolean
    Dim objVBProject As Object
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If Len(pProject) = 0 Then
        Set objVBProject = VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Else
        Set objVBProject = VBE.VBProjects(pProject)
    End If
    blnReturn = Len(objVBProject.VBComponents(pModule).Name) > 0

ExitHere:
    Set objVBProject = Nothing
    ModuleExists = blnReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9  ' Subscript out of range
        ' no such module; function returns False
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure ModuleExists"
        MsgBox strMsg
    End Select
    GoTo ExitHere
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I will check that Monday (it's nearly 9pm here).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. If you want to try it again, I have updated the link with the latest version 1.08. I use it often when receiving apps to review, to check the various ODBC links in the db, to quicly evaluate the complexity of the app, and to have a reference printed report before and after the rework.